# Javascript form submit: Object doesn't support this property or method (IE7)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm trying to submit a form with javascript. Firefox works fine but IE complains that "Object doesn't support this property or method" on the submit line of this function:

```
function submitPGV(formName, action)
{
    var gvString = "";

    pgVisibilities.each(function(pair) {
        gvString += pair.key + ":" + pair.value + ",";
    });

    $('pgv_input').value = gvString;

    var form = $(formName);
    form.action = action;
    form.submit();
}
```

Called here:

```
<a href="javascript:submitPGV('ProductGroupVisibility','config/productgroupvis/save')">
```

Here's the form:

```
<form id="ProductGroupVisibility" action="save" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="ows_gv..PGV" id="pgv_input" value=""/>
</form>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try checking the type of the element IE is selecting:

```
// For getting element with id you must use # 
alert( typeof( $( '#ProductGroupVisibility' )));
```

It is possible there is something else on the page with that ID that IE selects before the form.

Comment: Yep. I'm a moron. There was a table with id="productGroupVisibility", Firefox got the form, IE got the table.

I was sure I'd already tried changed the id on that table but I wasn't the one at the keyboard so who knows what happened.

Thanks heaps mate.

Comment: No problem.  Done it myself more than once ;)

Comment: Just want to add something that I've just seen that does the same thing. Different case, but same symptoms. Might help someone who stumbles on this answer.

"email = $('#UserEmail');"

No duplicate id, but IE didn't like that email wasn't officially declared. Changing to:
"var email = $('#UserEmail');"

Fixes the problem. This is more correct and I guess that's what happens when you get used to programming in more permissive environments. :)

Comment: This tip is invaluable. Fixed an issue I was having as well.

Answer (score 15):

What `name` does your `<input type="submit">` have?

If you called it "submit", you have overridden the `form.submit()` function, much the same way an input called "foo" would generate a `form.foo` property. That would explain the behavior.

Comment: I don't have an input of type submit. It's just the one hidden field that's submitted with javascript.

Comment: Good grace, I just tripped over exactly this problem, Tomalak. I owe you a beer ;-)

Comment: Same here. This is one of the little gems of SO. :)

Comment: just add a little bit, don't set the id either, that will do the same damage setting the submit method to the dom element.

Answer (score 3):

beware of any inputs in the form with name='submit', they break the javascript .submit() functionality!

Answer (score 1):

What javascript framework are you using? If it's jQuery I think you'll need to add # to your id:

```
$('#ProductGroupVisibility').submit();
```

Comment: Depends on the framework, and selected plugins.  Out-of-the-box mootools selects (at least v1.11 did) based on id with the syntax Kenny described.

Comment: Yah, I realized that after posting and edited my answer to specify jQuery. :)

Comment: Oh it's Prototype. Sorry I forgot to mention.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have your JavaScript library loaded? (jQuery or Prototype)

It worked for me in IE7 with Prototype.

Try:

```
alert($('ProductGroupVisibility').id)
```

See if you get an error.

Comment: You're right actually, it works for me if I put it into a dummy page with only the code listed above. It must be something else about the page. I'll amend my question with more info. Thanks for your help.