# submit a form using checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a very simple question - how do I get a form to submit when I change the status of a checkbox

Here is my code

```
<form name="formName" id="formName" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="get">
<input type ="checkbox" name="categories1" value = "1" onClick="submit();">1</input>
</form>
```

in addition to submit() I have tried:

- this.form.submit()
- document.getElementById('formName').submit()
- this.parentNode.submit()

but none of these work. When I check or uncheck the box nothing happen

any clues?

Comment: Your code is subject to XSS injection in the `action = "..."` bit. See exactly this question: [PHP_SELF and XSS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6080022/938236)

Comment: use this.form.submit instead of only submit(); if you want to submit form anyway.

Comment: `document.getElementById('formName').submit();` works.. can you show the `submit()` function

Answer (score 3):

Refer to the form name attribute:

```
document.formName.submit()
```

Comment: None of these suggestions work

Comment: when I try onclick="document.getElementById('formName').submit();" I get an error in IE saying 
Message: Object doesn't support this property or method

Answer (score 2):

This works for me in both FF and IE:

```
<form name="formName" id="formName" action="" method="get">
<input type ="checkbox" name="categories1" value = "1" onclick="this.form.submit();">1</input>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

found the problem - I had a submit button named submit - see [Javascript form submit: Object doesn't support this property or method (IE7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266794/javascript-form-submit-object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method-ie7) for similar soln.

Comment: You didn't share your input type having submit name,this is other problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
<form name="formName" id="formName" action="" method="get">
<input type ="checkbox" name="categories1" value = "1" **onchange**="this.form.submit();">1</input>
</form>
```