# jquery submit form by clicking checkbox doesn't work

Tags: jquery, forms

When clicking a checkbox the form should be submitted, but that doesn't happen. A simple alert (as a test) does work. Where does it go wrong?

HTML

```
<form id="formId" name="formName" action="index.php" method="post">
<input name=entry>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1">1
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox2">2
<input type="checkbox" onclick="this.form.submit();">5
<input type="submit" name="submit" >
</form>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(
  function(){ 
    $(".checkbox1").click(
        function(){ 
            alert('checkbox 1 clicked'); 
        }
    )
    $(".checkbox2").click(
        function(){ 
            $('#formId').submit();
        }
    )
    }
);
</script>
```

Comment: I haven't seen you have added any jquery library. are you?

Comment: I am a little puzzled how you got the alert to work either? The way the code is written neither should work. I will await updates before assuming my answer is correct (you may have just left out the rest of the code).

Comment: There is something very odd about this (still looking). My workaround (below) is to trigger the submit button instead when the checkbox is clicked. That submits just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the first issue below, I can see your form will not submit from any button press other than a submit button.

My workaround was to `trigger` a `click` event on your submit button instead of trying to submit the form with `.submit()`:

e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/tkdxg66m/1/

```
$(".checkbox2").click(
    function(){ 
        $('#submitme').trigger('click');
    }
)
```

**This is very odd behavior, as `submit()` should work, so I am looking into it further.**

---

*Older answer/issue below:*

You have wrapped your code in a function that is never called:

You probably meant to use a DOM ready handler like this:

```
       $(function(){
            $(".checkbox1").click(
                function(){ 
                    alert('checkbox 1 clicked'); 
                }
            )
            $(".checkbox2").click(
                function(){ 
                    $('#formId').submit();
                }
            )
        });
```

note: `$(function(){your code});` is a shortcut for `$(document).ready(function(){your code});`

or an IIFE (immediately invoked function expression) executing  like this:

```
       (function(){ 
            $(".checkbox1").click(
                function(){ 
                    alert('checkbox 1 clicked'); 
                }
            )
            $(".checkbox2").click(
                function(){ 
                    $('#formId').submit();
                }
            )
        })();
```

The DOM ready option makes more sense in this context :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use the jQuery code below. It will work for submitting a form.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(".checkbox2").click(
        function(){ 
           $("#formId").submit();
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Try his form HTML with your code in a JSFiddle... it does not submit.. Very odd indeed.

Comment: What exactly is the difference ? I originally left the document.ready code out for simplifying reasons. I have updated my original post. The code above is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Change "Click" to "Change" - I agree "Click" should work, but it doesn't always for me =/

Comment: dang you are on it today! was about to say same thing! 2nd answer you beat me too, lol

Answer (score 0):

Waddayaknow, problem solved! 
The thing was: i named the submit-button "submit". That causes the problem. I found this in other stackoverflow-threads; ([submit a form using checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158393/submit-a-form-using-checkbox?lq=1)) and: ([Javascript form submit: Object doesn't support this property or method (IE7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266794/javascript-form-submit-object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method-ie7)). Anyway, thanks for contributing.